# Angular Material SVG icon giving 404 error

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an SVG file in the same directory as app.component. I followed the [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/component/icon) example for using an icon in my html:

```
<md-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></md-icon>
```

The Typescript:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MdIconRegistry} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
   selector: 'icon-svg-example',
   templateUrl: './icon-svg-example.html',})

export class IconSvgExample {
  constructor(iconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
       'thumbs-up',
       sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/img/examples/thumbup-icon.svg'));
```

The icon doesn't show up when I run on the development server? I just get this error message in console:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/thumbs-up.svg 404 (Not Found)
Error retrieving icon: undefined
```

Comment: Try putting it in your `assets/img/examples` folder, since it's the path you provide.

Comment: @trichetriche Thankyou for that. It was an error with the path. How do you normally mark the question answered from a comment?

Comment: I will post an answer that you can upvote, or you can just upvote the comment on the left of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't mark it as resolved with a comment :

Try putting it in your assets/img/examples folder, since it's the path you provide